# c char pointer compare

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
struct list{
   char *Name;
};

void chekFC(struct list *newList){
  char *fC = newList->Name;
  printf("%s\n", &fC);                   //I can print it
  if(fC[0] == '+')                       //Any error??
  printf("Yes");
}

int main(){
   struct list *newList = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
   newList->Name = "+abc";
   chekFC(newList);
}
```

it can run, if I change the code to following

```
void chekFC(struct list *newList){
  char *fC = newList->Name;
  printf("%s\n", &fC);                   //I can print it
  if(fC[0] == '+')  {}                     // Add {}  nothing run in the if condition, than the program can run
  printf("Yes");
}
```

Why this program cannot run? The error is Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: You probably never initialized `newList->Name`...

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's wrong from just this code fragment. Please post the smallest complete program that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Show the full code, specifically the bit that allocates `newList->Name`

Comment: also don't cast the return of `malloc`, `void*` converts well to any object pointer type in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there have one problem in you code.

```
printf("%s\n", &fC);
```

you should change it to

```
printf("%s\n", fC);
```

I think you don't understand the C pointer very clearly.
the &fC is very different from fC, you can print it by "%p" to see it.

```
printf("fC %p, &fC %p\n", fC, &fC);
```

&fC is address of fC,
fC is address of string of "+abc".
I want it can help you, but I suggest you should read some book, to learn C pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `newList->Name` has been allocated?

Comment: I think so. Because I can print out Name from the newList.

Comment: by printf("@@%s\n", &newList->Name);

Comment: @Andreas, isn't the line newList->Name = "+abc"; an allocation in the text segment ?

Answer (score 1):

newList->name has never been allocated.

Comment: @dexametason, isn't the line newList->Name = "+abc"; an allocation in the text segment ?

Comment: He's not modifying it, so it's ok.  The pointer should be valid.

Answer (score 1):

To consistently avoid such problems in the future, I recommend using assertions:

```
assert(newList);
assert(newList->Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s\n", &fC);
```

is wrong, you probably mean

```
printf("%s\n", fC);
```

Comment: I cannot run the program if change to printf("%s\n", fC);

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: this is probably the fact that you cast the return of `malloc` because you are missing the correct `#include` for it.